# Mapping method results in Elasticsearch Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a child class on my model, PersonName.

```
public class PersonName
{
    public string Prefix { get; set;  }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleNames { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }

    public string GetFullName() => StringExtensions.ConcatNonEmpty(" ", FirstName, LastName);
}
```

I want to index the result of GetFullName.

```
.Object<PersonName>(o => o
   .Name(n => n.Name)
   .AutoMap()
   .Properties(p => p
      .Text(t => t
         .Name(n2 => n2.FirstName)
         .Analyzer(Ananlysis.AutocompleteAnalyzerName)
         .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
       ).Text(t => t
          .Name(n2 => n2.MiddleNames)
          .Analyzer(Ananlysis.AutocompleteAnalyzerName)
          .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
       ).Text(t => t
          .Name(n2 => n2.LastName)
          .Analyzer(Ananlysis.AutocompleteAnalyzerName)
          .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
       )
       // Here is what I'd like to do
       .Text(t => t
          .Name("name.full")
          .Value(v => v.GetFullName())) // <--- something like this
    ) 
  )
)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What if you just change `GetFullName` to a getter-only property `FullName`? That said, I am interested if you can do it the way you want to :)

Comment: Why do you need to add the value to the index when you already have the values?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund because I want to add an autocomplete analyzer on the full name. Still quite new to ES so experimenting with it.

Comment: @John this is my fall back.  :)